# How to calculate the $H_2$ and $H_\infty$ norms of TransferFunctionModels or StateSpaceModels?

Tags: control-systems

Lets assume we have a system model:

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{
     (s^3 - 2.841 s^2 + 2.875 s - 1.004)/
      (s^3 - 2.417 s^2 + 2.003 s - 0.5488)}}, s];
ss = StateSpaceModel[tf]
```

[image]

**My question is:**

How to calculate $H_2$ and $H_\infty$ norms of this system or transfer function?
Is there a built-in function for it?

**Some notes:**

- In MATLAB `norm(ss,2)` or `norm(ss,inf)` does that.
- Mathematical calculations can be done as in this [link](http://dali.feld.cvut.cz/ucebna/matlab/toolbox/control/norm.html).

From the `LyapunovSolve` examples one can compute the $H_2$ norm of an asymptotically stable continuous-time system as below:

```
{a, b, c} = {{{-1, 2, 3}, {0, -2, 2}, {0, 0, -3}},
             {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}},
             {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}};

x = LyapunovSolve[a, -b.Transpose[b]];
h2norm = Sqrt[Tr[c.x.Transpose[c]]] // N
```

> 6.12917

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $H_2$ norm can be computed as $\sqrt{\text{Trace}\left(b q b^{\dagger}\right)}$ or $\sqrt{\text{Trace}\left(c p c^{\dagger}\right)}$. Here $b$ and $c$ are the input and output matrices of $ss$, and $q$ and $p$ are the observability and controllability gramians.

However if you tried `ObservabilityGramian[ss]` there is an error because this particular system is unstable and hence its $H_2$ norm is $\infty$.

The $H_{\infty }$ norm can be obtained from the peak value of the the `SingularValuePlot` (or magnitude plot in `BodePlot`).

```
SingularValuePlot[tf]
```

This turns out to be $\sim 5.2 db$ for this system.

[image]

(Unfortunately, no built-in functions yet for the norm computations.)

Comment: what kind of transpose/inverse is it?

Comment: `ConjugateTranspose`

Comment: This is quite of a lack in the available functionalities.